# BizTalk Tracking Keeps Turning Off

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

On my development machine, I'm seeing that the tracking on the XMLReceive/XmlTransmit pipelines are being turned off every time I do a deploy from Visual Studio (of any other project).

I don't recall this happening in the past places that I've worked.  Is this the normal behavior?

Similarly in a testing environment on another machine, the tracking is often going off, most likely with MSI deploys.  We always want the tracking on in the development and testing environments.

Under the application "BizTalk.System" in BizTalk Admin console, the checkboxes below get turned off, and I have to frequently turn them back on.

[image]

As a backup plan, I found this script that can turn it back on.  I hate to call this script every time I do a deploy in Visual Studio:
https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/LoggingAndMonitoring%2FMicrosoft%20BizTalk%20Server%20-%20Logging?doc=/Getting%20started/2.%20Recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this occurs if in the bindings for an application you have tracking disabled on that pipeline.

If you are using BTDF you can tokenize the tracking settings as per my blog article [Tokenizing the BizTalk Tracking Settings](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2017/08/11/tokenizing-the-biztalk-tracking-settings/)

For Orchestrations

`<Service …… TrackingOption="${Orchestration_Tracking}" >`

In the Send and Receive Ports

`<Tracking>${OneWay_SendPort_Tracking}</Tracking>`
​

And the Pipelines

`<ReceivePipeline …. TrackingOption="${Pipeline_Tracking}" />`

The other option is to create custom pipelines, containing the same Pipeline Components as the default ones (e.g. one with XML Assembler & and one with a XML Disassembler)

Comment: Thanks, my current client doesn't want to use BTDF.  Can you explain more "Yes, this occurs if in the bindings for an application you have tracking disabled on that pipeline."  I have all tracking turned on.  I don't understand why the common XMLReceive/XMLTransmit would changed based on anything in my application.

Comment: @NealWalters  Check the tracking setting in the ReceivePipeline and SendPipeline in your bindings. If you aren't applying bindings, make sure you clear out the folder Delete all the files from the folder %APPDATA%\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles\   as it can cache old copies there.   Yes, it is strange behaviour  and yes, you would think an application settings should not affect the common ones, but it does.  The other option is to create custom pipelines for your solution that contains the same component as the default ones.